# Python Dataframe: operation per row in all dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in python which looks like the following. The number of column is not fix and increase with a iteration but follows the same pattern (more columns can be added), but to illustrate my issue please take my current `df`.

```
           0          1          2
0   0.414143  13.898568  17.322851
1  24.348445   0.514046  36.663878
0   0.776340  11.541118  21.312318
0  11.700539  56.442854  22.853285
2  11.599149  12.977594   4.905724
1  22.944083   0.501586  42.553746
0   4.092333  39.273114  23.406309
```

The idea is to keep the same `dataframe` dimension and compute the min value per row and set zero to the others values in the same row. The final results should look like this:

```
           0          1          2
0   0.414143          0          0
1          0   0.514046          0
0   0.776340          0          0
0  11.700539          0          0
2          0          0   4.905724
1          0   0.501586          0
0   4.092333          0          0
```

I set the row and column index with the same format (*This indexes are integers in a range between [0-9]*. The value which match with the same index, is the value that I'd like to keep it and set others as zeros.

*Any idea which function could I apply to achieve my goal?*

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** same answer applied to an updated DF:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
           0          1          2
0   0.414143  13.898568  17.322851
1  24.348445   0.514046  36.663878
0   0.776340  11.541118  21.312318
0  11.700539  56.442854  22.853285
2  11.599149  12.977594   4.905724
1  22.944083   0.501586  42.553746
0   4.092333  39.273114  23.406309

In [135]: df[~df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)] = 0

In [136]: df
Out[136]:
           0         1         2
0   0.414143  0.000000  0.000000
1   0.000000  0.514046  0.000000
0   0.776340  0.000000  0.000000
0  11.700539  0.000000  0.000000
2   0.000000  0.000000  4.905724
1   0.000000  0.501586  0.000000
0   4.092333  0.000000  0.000000
```

**Old answer:**

One of many possible ways:

```
In [108]: df[~df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)] = 0

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
           0          1
1   0.000000  13.898568
1   0.000000   0.514046
1   0.000000  11.541118
1   0.000000  12.977594
0  11.700539   0.000000
1   0.000000   0.501586
0   2.358687   0.000000
0  22.853285   0.000000
```

Comment: This codes works very well when I only have two columns. If I add more (see my comments "columns are not fix" your code does not work.

Comment: @CamiloRomero, it works just fine for me - see updated answer

Comment: @CamiloRomero, glad I could help:)